# I'm having trouble installing wxPython on OS X 10.10.2

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, osx-yosemite

The [wxpython installation instructions](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#osx) say:

> Be sure to download the image that matches the version of Python that
>   you want to use it with.

Well, gee willickers.  I have a system install of python2.7, and I have my own install of python2.7.  How do I tell wxPython to install in my python2.7 and not the system python2.7?

Next, I tried to install from source. The instructions in wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/docs/readme.txt say:

> For installation information, please see the install.txt file in the
>   docs subdirectory appropriate for the platform you use, e.g.
>   docs/msw/install.txt.

And, the instructions in `wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/docs/osx/install.txt` say:

```
In wxWidgets 3, Cocoa is the recommended library. 
...
... 
# Build the library for Cocoa (wxWidgets 2.9.0 and later)
mkdir build-cocoa-debug
cd build-cocoa-debug
../configure --enable-debug
make
# Build the samples and demos
cd samples; make;cd ..
cd demos;   make;cd ..
```

No `$ make install`?  In any case, `make` ended with these problems:

```
../src/osx/webview_webkit.mm:392:30: warning: incompatible pointer types sending
      'WebViewUIDelegate *' to parameter of type 'id<WKUIDelegate>'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    [m_webView setUIDelegate:uiDelegate];
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
../src/osx/webview_webkit.mm:464:34: warning: 'WKPreferences' may not respond to
      'setUsesPageCache:'
        [[m_webView preferences] setUsesPageCache:NO];
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
../src/osx/webview_webkit.mm:466:34: warning: 'WKPreferences' may not respond to
      'setUsesPageCache:'
        [[m_webView preferences] setUsesPageCache:YES];
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
../src/osx/webview_webkit.mm:936:25: error: cannot initialize a variable of type
      'WebBackForwardList *' with an rvalue of type 'WKBackForwardList *'
    WebBackForwardList* history = [m_webView backForwardList];
                        ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/osx/webview_webkit.mm:954:25: error: cannot initialize a variable of type
      'WebBackForwardList *' with an rvalue of type 'WKBackForwardList *'
    WebBackForwardList* history = [m_webView backForwardList];
                        ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [webviewdll_osx_webview_webkit.o] Error 1
$
```

OSX 10.10.2

**Edit:**

The install docs in the source distribution talk about avoiding installing wxPython in the system python, so I went ahead and used the binary installer for python2.7 (the .dmg file), trusting that it wouldn't install in the system python, and it appears to have successfully installed in my python2.7:

```
~$ python 
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>>
```

My system python has a different minor version:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.6
```

Although, my python2.7 happens to be the first python in my PATH, so maybe the installer just chose the first python2.7 it found.  If I remember correctly, when you install your own python2.7, the installer adjusts the PATH environment variable (in ~/.bash_profile) to put the directory containing your python2.7 ahead of the directory that contains the system's python.

So if you did a regular install for your own python2.7, then installing wxPython will find your python2.7 rather than the system's python2.7.

Comment: So did you resolve the issue you were having? By the way, I have successfully install wxPython to my system Python on a Mac. The main problems I've heard about doing that is that freezing my app using py2app may not work correctly.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll, Yes.  Why would you want to install wxPython in your system python?

Comment: Mostly for convenience so I wouldn't have to install two parallel versions of Python 2. But I'll probably end up doing that anyway. I recently discovered that you HAVE to install Kivy to your Mac's system Python to use it properly, but that doesn't really have anything to do with wx.